# What function(s) to use for identifying substring of column value?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I need identify a **base** sku so I can label child skus, for the purpose of organizing their colors.

So the sku column will contain values like CEN123A, CEN123B, CEN123C etc. where CEN123A is the parent and the rest which share the same number are children. I need a function that identifies the parent so I can label the children and fill in their corresponding values.

So ideally a column that labels CEN123A as "Parent" and the rest "Children". The value looks like this (CEN120A/CEN120D):

[image]

I tried `=COUNTIF(A$2:A2,LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))&"*")=1` but this will find only if the sku is a unique value, so CEN123A and CEN123B would be considered different. I need them to be considered the same because they both have CEN123*.

Comment: Fixed, sorry for that.

Comment: `FIND("-",A2)-1` would ignore the A, B, C, D, etc

Comment: Thanks although ... Hmm, maybe I asked wrong. I'm still getting TRUE for CEN123A & B, whereas I would prefer CEN123* to be true only for the first unique value. So in the case of CEN123A/B/C it would only be true for A.

Comment: `FIND("-",A2)-2` -> `...-0` = "CEN120A-"; `...-1` = "CEN120A"; `...-2` = "CEN120";

Comment: It you're ever confused, while building formulas, as to why you're not getting the expected result, take the formula apart piece by piece. For example, looking at just `LEFT(A2,FIND("-",A2))` would allow you to play with the values until you get the expected result, then putting it back into the larger formula.